# How to format a TimePeriod in julia

Tags: julia

How do you format a TimePeriod in julia as `MM:SS`?

```
tp = DateTime(2000) - DateTime(1000)
Dates.format(tp, "mm:ss")
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Dates.format(tp, "mm:ss")`? Have you tried `"MM:SS"`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: well, have you? That's not the issue here..

Comment: @Antonello My point was that it is not apparent from the question what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `format` works for `Date` or `DateTime` objects, not for `TimePeriod` ones.
Your example is however "simple", as both `DateTime(1000)` and `DateTime(2000)` take exactly midnights, so there is no approximation error using the `Minute()` function (and seconds are 0):

```
julia> using Dates

julia> dt1 = DateTime(1000)
1000-01-01T00:00:00

julia> dt2 = DateTime(2000)
2000-01-01T00:00:00

julia> tp = dt2 - dt1 # milliseconds
31556908800000 milliseconds

julia> min = Minute(tp)
525948480 minutes

julia> min_man = tp/(1000*60) # to check...
525948480 milliseconds
```

We would have a little bit more complicate example if we would take as ending DateTime a slightly later time:

```
julia> dt1 = DateTime(1000)
1000-01-01T00:00:00

julia> dt2 = DateTime(2000,01,01,00,02,30) # past two minutes 30 seconds
2000-01-01T00:02:30

julia> tp = dt2 - dt1           # milliseconds
31556908950000 milliseconds
```

In this case if we try the method above, we would have a InexactError:

```
julia> # min = Minute(tp)       Would raise InexactError  
       # min_man = tp/(1000*60) Would raise InexactError
```

We need hence to do the computation manually taking the values stored in `tp` and knowing it represents milliseconds:

```
 julia> tp.value
31556908950000

julia> min = Int(floor(tp.value/(1000*60)))
525948482

julia> sec = Int(ceil((tp.value - min*60*1000)/1000))
30

julia> println("$min:$sec")
525948482:30
```

For a nice overview of the `Date` module see also my tutorial on [https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/dev/01_-*JULIA1*-*Basic_Julia_programming/0103*-_Predefined_types.html#Date-and-time-Date,-DateTime](https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/dev/01_-_JULIA1_-_Basic_Julia_programming/0103_-_Predefined_types.html#Date-and-time-Date,-DateTime)

Answer (score -2):

Try using the following to format a time period. You cannot directly subtract DateTimes in Julia. This will result in an error. I am assuming what you are entering as a Date time in years? Or convert directly using `Dates.Period(<mytime>)`

```
using Dates

dt1 = DateTime(2000)
dt2 = DateTime(1000)

time_difference = year(dt1) - year(dt2)  # Calculate the difference in years
period_difference = Dates.Period(Dates.Year(time_difference))  # Convert to a Period object

formatted_time = Dates.format(period_difference, "MM:SS")
```